# Menu Lateral com Bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap

Estou com dificuldades em desenvolver um menu lateral com bootstrap 4 a ideia é ao invés de abrir para baixo expandir para cima quando fechar ele abrir na lateral do site quando estiver em uma tela mobile.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Fábio poste na pergunta o que você tem de código pronto, HTML, CSS, etc. Se possível coloque uma imagem do design que pretende ter no menu, aberto e fechado, direita ou esquerda.

Comment: No momento apenas estou usando a versão 4 do bootstrap e o menu está no estado padrão do bootstrap.

Comment: Essa é a documentação oficial do NavBar. Acho que com as Classes default do BS4 vc não vai conseguir. https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/

Comment: sabe como  ou onde consigo ver um tutorial sobre a criação desde menu

Comment: Fábio vc pode usar o BS4 mas fazer o Menu de outra forma, ou até na mão mesmo. Procure no codepen.io por "hamburger menu", ou no youtube por "canvas menu"